# jstl can't get <c:if test ... > to work with variable and string

Tags: jstl

I am writing code to add a "Help" menu item if a help text file exists for a given webpage and contains a non-empty string. For some reason, I can't get the test line to work. Here is the simplified code I'm using to debug the problem:

```
<c:import var="data" url="${file}" />
alert(${data});
<c:if test="${data == 'Hello'}" />
    (code to add "Help" menu item)
</c:if>
```

The file that is being read contains 'Hello' (including the single quotes), so the test line should return true and the code to add the Help menu item should execute. The alert line displays Hello, indicating that the file has been successfully read; but the test fails, and the code to add Help menu item DOES NOT execute. I would appreciate any ideas on what I am doing wrong. As a side note, I thought that the alert line should be alert("${data}"); but it doesn't work with the quotes.

Comment: What does  zzz<c:import url="${file}" />zzz   print?  You might be getting white space along with the word Hello. Also, look at source code that was sent to browser. There might be some HTML tags sent as well.

Comment: It printed the following:
ZZZ'Hello'
ZZZ

Comment: My edits to the previous comment didn't make it under the 5 min limit. It printed the following:
ZZZ'Hello'
ZZZ with the last three Zs on a newline.
Does the <c: import ... command automatically add a return? I opened the file with vi and verified that there are no spaces or extra lines. It contains exactly 'Hello'. Can I use the jstl trim command to remove the return?

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:import var="data" url="${file}" />
<c:set var="data" value="${fn:trim(data)}" />
alert("${data}");
<c:if test="${data == 'Hello'}" />
        (code to add "Help" menu item)
</c:if>
```

Comment: rickz, thank you for your suggestion, it helped me find the solution. For some reason, <c:import ... appears to add a line feed, which I now remove with the trim command. Getting rid of the line feed also allowed me to use proper syntax in the alert line. Finally, I removed the single quotes in the file, so it now contains just Hello.

Comment: Great! I am glad that you found solution. Extra white space is common in JSP.  You might be able to avoid it with a page directive attribute. I didn't test my idea.